# (AuthComponent::user('role') in cakephp not returning data correctly in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

Login:

```
public function login(){
    if($this->request->is('post')){

        if($this->Auth->login($this->request->data)){
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }else{
            $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid Username or Password');
        }
    }

}
```

This return value:

```
if(AuthComponent::user()
```

But when I use this:

```
if((AuthComponent::user('role'))==1)
```

It does't return value at all

I can login-logout normally

Answer (score 0):

When authenticating users, attached authentication objects are checked in the order they are attached. Once one of the objects can identify the user, no other objects are checked. A sample login function for working with a login form could look like:

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        // Important: Use login() without arguments! See warning below.
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            // Prior to 2.3 use
            // `return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());`
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(
            __('Username or password is incorrect'),
            'default',
            array(),
            'auth'
        );
    }
}
```

The above code (without any data passed to the login method), will attempt to log a user in using the POST data, and if successful redirect the user to either the last page they were visiting, or AuthComponent::$loginRedirect. If the login is unsuccessful, a flash message is set.

In 2.x `$this->Auth->login($this->request->data)` will log the user in with whatever data is posted, whereas in 1.3 `$this->Auth->login($this->data)` would try to identify the user first and only log in when successful.